# problem with margin in wave svg or parent padding

Tags: html, css, svg, wave

i use a wave `svg`. but when use it margin under that while there is no margin or padding in elements
what is problem?
My Code:

```css
body {
    background-color: lightgray;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Source Sans 3";
}

.topheader,
.left,
.right {
    display: flex;
}

.left,
.right {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.right {
    justify-content: end;

}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    /* border: 1px solid; */
}

ul li {
    padding: 13px 5px;
    font-family: "Source Sans 3";
    font-size: 16px;
    /* border: 1px solid; */
}

.left ul li:hover {
    background-color: #04aa6d;

}

.left ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

.topheader ul li a {
    color: #000;
}

ul li,
header a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

}

ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}



.right li>a {

    padding: 2px 15px;
}

.right li a.det:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.right li:nth-child(2) span {
    color: #04aa6d;
}

.right li:nth-child(3) span {
    color: #9763f6;
}

.reg {
    /* background-color: #d9eee1; */
    display: flex;
    padding: 0px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.reg a:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #04aa6d;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    z-index: 0;
}

.reg a:nth-child(1):hover {
    background-color: #059862;
}

.reg a:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #d9eee1;
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}

.reg .log:hover {
    background-color: #059862;
}

.menubar {
    background-color: #282a35;
    /* height: 100px; */
    display: flex;
}

.mun {
    margin: 0 3px;
    padding: 0;
}

.mun li {
    color: #c2c3c5;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}


.menuicon {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}



.menuicon span {
    color: #c2c3c5;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 27px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.top {

    background-color: #282a35;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    /* position: relative;
    height: 350px; */
}

.top p:nth-child(1) {
    font-size: 70px;
    line-height: 105px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.top p {
    margin: 0;
    /* margin-bottom: 0; */
    padding: 0;

}

.top .title {
    color: #ffc0c7;
    font-size: 23px;
}

.searchbox {
    text-align: center;
    /* margin: 40px; */
    /* border: 1px solid #fff; */
    padding: 10px;
}

.searchbox .container {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 500px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    margin: auto;
    /* padding: 15px 5px; */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.searchbox .container input {
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.searchbox .container a {
    background-color: #04aa6d;
    padding: 5px 40px;
    /* display: flex; */
}

.searchbox .container a span {
    line-height: 40px;

}

a.notsure {
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 23px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    padding: 40px 0;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
}

.courses .html {
    background-color: #d9eee1;
    display: flex;

    justify-content: space-around;
    height: 250px;
}

.courses .html .left {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    /* height: 300px; */
}

.courses .html .left .btns {
    background-color: #04AA6D;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 8px 16px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+3">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+3&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <div class="topheader">
                <div class="left">
                    <img src="img/w3.png" alt="" width="40px">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Toturials
                                <span class="material-symbols-outlined">arrow_drop_down</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Exercises
                                <span class="material-symbols-outlined">arrow_drop_down</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Get Certificated <span
                                    class="material-symbols-outlined">arrow_drop_down</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Services <span class="material-symbols-outlined">arrow_drop_down</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="det"><a href=""><span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                                    military_tech
                                </span>Bootcamps</a></li>
                        <li class="det"><a href=""><span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                                    redeem
                                </span>Spaces</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="reg">
                                <a id="a1" href="">Sign Up</a>
                                <a id="a2" href="" class="log">Log in</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="menubar">
                <ul class="mun">
                    <li>HTML</li>
                    <li>CSS</li>
                    <li>JAVASCRIPT</li>
                    <li>SQL</li>
                    <li>PYTHON</li>
                    <li>JAVA</li>
                    <li>PHP</li>
                    <li>BOOTSTRAP</li>
                    <li>HOW TO</li>
                    <li>W3.CSS</li>
                    <li>C</li>
                    <li>C++</li>
                    <li>C#</li>
                    <li>REACT</li>
                    <li>R</li>
                    <li>JQUERY</li>
                    <li>DJANGO</li>
                    <li>TYPESCRIPT</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="menuicon">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                        dark_mode
                    </span>
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                        public
                    </span>
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                        search
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <section class="top">
            <p>Learn to Code</p>
            <p class="title">With the world's largest web developer site.</p>
            <div class="searchbox">
                <div class="container">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search our tutorials, e.g. HTML">
                    <a href="#"> <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                            search
                        </span></a>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="notsure">Not Sure Where To Begin?</a>

            </div>

            <svg class="svg" style="background-color:#D9EEE1;" width="100%" height="70" viewBox="0 0 100 100"
                preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <path id="wavepath" d="M0,0  L110,0C35,150 35,0 0,100z" fill="#282A35"></path>
            </svg>
          
    
        </section>
        <section class="courses">
            <div class="html">
                <div class="left">
                    <a class="btns" id="learn">Learn HTML</a>
                    <a class="btns" id="video">Video Toturial</a>
                    <a class="btns" id="refrence">HTML Refrences</a>
                    <a class="btns" id="get">Get Certificated</a>
                </div>
                <div class="right">vj</div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use `.svg{display:block;}` in the css

Comment: ok thanks what was the reason?